# What causes Visual Studio to hide files on some machines but not others?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution which appears to be fine on one machine, but on another machine it has decided to hide all of the files in a single project.

None of the nodes can be double-clicked, and Studio refuses to allow any context menus to function.

What might cause this effect in Visual Studio?

[image]

The source appears to be identical on both machines. Is this some strange option I've triggered? Restarting Visual Studio appears to have no effect.

**Update**: If I click the ShowAllFiles button at the top of the solution the organisation of the project changes to the following:

[image]

This appears to be the root of my c: drive.

Also, FWIW, I have 8 other projects in this solution. None of them have this issue on either machine.

8/9 projects (including the problematic one) are console applications. The 9th is a library which the others all use.

Comment: Are both machines using the same version of Visual Studio?

Comment: You may want to execute the Menu Item: Project | Retarget Solution, then rebuild the solution.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes same version. Upgraded both machines to latest available within the last week.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Results in "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." Most context menus items result in similar errrors.

Comment: Are there any absolute file paths hardcoded into the project files? Are there any macros used that may differ between both systems?

Comment: @fabian No hard coded paths. I opened the .vcxproj file in notepad and looked through it. I'm not sure how I'd have used a macro. I'm quite the beginner in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this appears to have been solved now.

It seems the answer to this was to **delete the .vs folder** for the solution.
I guess something got corrupted in the copy on one machine.

Please note that this appeared to screw up the compilation of the entire solution at first.
However it turns out that it just forgot which platform was the default.

In my case I'd setup all settings to compile for x86 and the solution defaulted back to x64, which I had no configuration for and as such all the headers appeared to go missing.

Hopefully this answer will help someone else out if they should find themselves in a similar scenario.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: My apologies @Jeaninez-MSFT. I had forgotten that this was an option. Thanks for the reminder.  :)